# Python - retrieved different result when using curl and requests library

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to build a python crawler using `requests` library. When i use `get` method i retrieved result look like: `THá» THAO`. But when i use `curl` i got `THỂ THAO` and it is my expected result. Here is my code:

```
def get_raw_channel():
    r = requests.get('http://vtv.vn/')
    raw_html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
    o_tags = soup.find_all("option")
    for o_tag in o_tags:
        print o_tag.text
        # raw_channel = RawChannel(o_tag.text.strip(), o_tag['value'])
        # channels_file.write(raw_channel.__str__() + '\n')
```

Here is my curl cmd: `curl http://vtv.vn/`

**Question:** why the results is different? How can i achieve `curl`'s result by using `requests`?

Comment: What is the encoding of the response body?

Comment: @LutzHorn
`(Date: Mon, 09 Feb 2015 07:59:34 GMT, Content-Type: text/html, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Connection: close, Vary: Accept-Encoding ,Server: vtv-rp`
this is curl response header. And:
`{'via': '1.1 TMG', 'proxy-connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunk
ed', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'vtv-rp', 'connection': 'Keep-Alive',
'date': 'Mon, 09 Feb 2015 08:19:52 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html'}` is requests response headers.

Comment: @LutzHorn i dont see encoding of response. But i think it is `utf-8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and in my case the encoding was 'ISO-8859-1', try to encode your data into UTF-8 before process it in BS, something like:

```
...
raw_html = r.text.encode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
...
```

**UPDATE:**
I made some more tests, looks like everything worked for me because I explicitly set encoding for request, take a look

```
In [1]: import requests
In [2]: from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
In [3]: r = requests.get('http://vtv.vn/')
In [4]: r.encoding = "utf-8"
In [5]: raw_html = r.text
In [6]: soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
In [7]: soup.findAll("option")
Out[7]: 
[<option value="1">
 VTV1</option>,
 ... stripped out some output ...

 VTVCab3 - Thể thao TV</option>,
 <option value="13">

 ... stripped out some output ...
]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it does not work with me :(